# Сравнения очень больших текстовых файлов

Tags: c#

Собственно есть 2 текстовых файла, весом 10+гб, в каждом множество строк длинной не более 64 символов, как сравнить эти два файла не загружаю в оперативку, получив два других, где будут уникальные вхождения и дубликаты

Comment: консоль + patch

Comment: уникальные вхождения и дубликаты чего ? (слов, предложений, строк, морфем, лексем, чего то еще)

Comment: дубликаты строк

Comment: грузя файлы блоками, влезающими в оперативку, отсортировать строки в блоках. Выполнить окончательную сортировку файлов, используя алгоритм сортировки слиянием. Полученные сортированные файлы сравнивать вычитывая параллельно небольшими блоками и продвигая указатель в файле где строка "меньше" (алгоритм практически идентичен сортировки слиянием). Так же можно работать не над самими строками, а над их контрольными суммами, что бы сортируемые массивы были меньше объемом и было проще сортировать

Comment: Если работать с контрольными суммами можно использовать не сортировку блоков и потом сортировку слиянием, а сортировку методом разбития на мелкие файлы, каждый из которых содержит определенный диапазон значений. С последующей сортировкой мелких файлов и их использование в конечном сравнении вместо больших сортированных файлов. В принципе то же выполнимо и непосредственно над строками, но там сложнее разбить на боле менее одинаковые по размеру мелкие файлы ввиду отсутствия нормального распределения у значений

Comment: 1) отсортировать оба файла 2) сравнить эти файлы

Comment: Обратиться к поиску с ключевым словом `diff` :)

Comment: Чтобы не грузить в оперативку - MemoryMappedFiles. Главное чтобы хватило виртуальной памяти.

Comment: MemoryMappedFiles я думаю это ключ к решению, но есть еще одна загвоздка, если брать два цикла и считывать один и второй файл, и сравнивать, то это будет очень долго, есть ли какой то алгоритм что бы считывать только один файл и проверять наличие в stream нужной строки в другом файле?